# Does Image Hosting affects CPU usage on webservers?

Tags: webserver, image-hosting

I am working on an android app in which i am including an image gallery. The images will be stored on Webserver and will be accessible by app.
I want to know that if I only store images on webserver and 1 webpage. Will the Hotlinking of images from server in my app, affect CPU usage on webservers?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host that is serving the image will consume resources every time that image is accessed, so for example:

`App.com` has HTML page 
`image.com` has the images, every time that app.com is accessed resources are used on app.com to serve the HTML and image.com server will consume resources serving the images. So, yes CPU/RAM is used.

Comment: Can you suggest any free image host with wide bandwidth and a static url to your image directory?

Comment: Sorry don't know any, I personally keep away from services that are free because there's always hidden restrictions and creates more work later on - I'm sure there are plenty, check Google ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because images are typically static they often don't strain resources the same way that dynamic pages do.   Dynamic pages typically put strain on:

- The CPU
- The Database

Images typically strain

- Number of simultaneous requests
- Disk IO
- Bandwidth

It is likely that you can serve a fair number of image requests from your server without bogging it down.

If the images are making your server slow, the typical way to deal with them is to

- Optimize them with image shrinking programs
- Serve images that are the correct size to display in the browser rather serving large ones that are scaled down at the user end
- Combine many images into one (spriting)
- Move them to a content delivery network (CDN)

See [Yahoo's guide for speeding up your website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) which has good explanations on all of those items.

Comment: I have tried it once on free hosting. My host was serving some data from webpages  to my android app. I got 6000 downloads in two days. my site was down for 24 hrs. in 48hrs.. Means that my app was also not fuctioning properly.
At the other side, i don't want to invest money on VPS hosting and all. I am searching for some good free image host with static url to image directory.

Comment: @Ashutosh you can't expect to get everything for free. CDNs are not expensive. If you have a lot of usage for your app you should be receiving some form of income from that.

Comment: To be honest hosting is just as important as the functionality of the app, if app gets 3,000 downloads per a day it should be pretty easy to get funding for some decent hosting that is not expensive as @DisgruntledGoat has suggested.